# Javascript function to convert an array of objects to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am doing and web application and I need to implement a function that converts this array of objects in javascript to an "ul" in HTML but I don´t know, so maybe you could help me...

I have task items saved in a database and this is the result that the database gives me when I call a GET function from DB:

```
{"code": "ok", "data": [
        {"done": 1, "deadline": "2012-11-09", "id": 1, "desc": "Go to run"}, 
        {"done": 0, "deadline": "2012-11-09", "id": 2, "desc": "Go to doctor"}, 
        {"done": 0, "deadline": "2012-11-08", "id": 3, "desc": "Go to buy"}
]}
```

I have to put each task object in an HTML "ul" like this:

```
<ul>
<a href="#dialog"><li data-task-id="1">
    <p class="desc">Go to run</p>
    <time datetime="2012-11-09">09/11/2012</time>
    <p class="done" data-task-done="yes">done</p>
</li></a>

<a href="#dialog"><li data-task-id="1">
    <p class="desc">Go to doctor</p>
    <time datetime="2012-11-09">09/11/2012</time>
    <p class="done" data-task-done="yes">done</p>
</li></a>

<a href="#dialog"><li data-task-id="2">
    <p class="desc">Go to buy</p>
    <time datetime="2012-11-09">09/11/2012</time>
    <p class="done" data-task-done="no">not done</p>
</li></a>
```

I need an JavaScript function to create this html code from arrays.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm sure you're not just asking someone to write your code for you *(at least I hope that's not the case)*, so maybe you could explain where you're stuck.

Comment: ...FYI, the HTML result you describe is invalid.

Comment: It's not an array of arrays, it is an array of objects.

Comment: I edit the question, now it is more specific. I apologize for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the Array

```
var arr = YOUR_DATA.data;
var code = "";
for ( var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // This is called for every Item

    var currentItem = arr[i];
    // This is your Item

    code += '<a [...] <p class="desc">' + currentItem.desc + '</p> [...]'
    /*
        Just replace the brackets and write your HTML Code in there
        If there is a variable write " '+currentItem.VAR_NAME+' "
    */
}
```